# Unable to open blender due to SDL2 pop up

Tags: installation

I recently installed Blender 2.79b into my laptop (Windows 10 x64 Version 10.0.15063). I began getting the following pop up message right after trying to open the program.

[image: Blender bad Image pop up]

Has anyone gotten this pop up?

Any way to fix this?

Comment: Did you download the 32bit version by accident? You can also download the Standalone version which comes in a ZIP. Extract the archive anywhere you like including a USB drive and run it directly from there. Also an antivirus program maybe scanning the file at the moment windows opens it for Blender. Try rebooting.

Comment: Hey Rob. I did uninstall it and went with the zip version. It still got the same error. The anti virus didn't interfere with the file.

Comment: Rob. I just rebooted. Still the same result.

Comment: Unfortunately that indicates that it is your machine at fault. If possible uninstall and reinstall all your graphic drivers. I have found in the past that installing a demo of new game will often force graphic updates. After that you could check the BIOS and make sure the graphic card settings are correct, i.e. if there is an integrated graphics chip that is interfering with the main graphics card.